# changing visibility of TD's (swapping one with another with display style) appears wrong in firefox, chrome

Tags: javascript, html

Solved, please read below.

I have a table with several columns. For each column there is one hidden column with an input box that the user can toggle to enable filtering for that column. Both td's share the exact same setup, apart from its contents. This is the setup for "one" column

```
<td id="MainContent_gdComponentsHead2" class="tdHead" width="88px" onclick="..">Type</td>
<td id="MainContent_gdComponentsInput2" class="tdHead" width="88px" style="display:none"><input id="MainContent_gdComponents_filter2" onkeydown=".." type="text" class="tdHeadInput" value="" />&nbsp;</td>
<td class="tdHeadEdit" onclick="MainContent_gdComponents_toggleFilter('MainContent_gdComponents','2','MainContent_gdComponents_filter2')" style="width:9px">..</td>
```

I cant for the life of me figure out why, when the swap occures (the head column set to display:none and the input column set to display:block), that in chrome and firefox (possibly also opera) the column gets overlapped, it doesnt retain its boxed poition. It gets shifted left as if it has 0px width. The tdHeadInput class has width and height set to 100%. The input shows ok, but it is floating on top of the next column. The column that holds the input box appears as a 0px width box (i.e gone).

Any ideas? :)

...

Ok, I guess I was impatient when asking this question. After googling and trying different stuff I figured out a solution. I dont know why, but I had to use display='' instead of display='block'. It then works in IE, firefox and chrome. The odd thing is that I have a bunch of other stuff in my website that uses display='block' (all through javascript) and they all work fine. It was just this one, which happens to be a TD in a table. Is there a difference here?

If anyone knows anything about this, please comment :) But the original question is noe solved.

Comment: You don't need to use `display=""`, you should instead use `display: table-cell`. The first supplies an invalid value to the `display` property, which causes the browser to disregard it, and fall back to the 'default' value for that property for that element-type. The latter is the default `display` property for a `td` element. Incidentally, please post your answer *as an answer*, not just an update to the question.